# Coding the Python way

Tags: python

I've just spent the last half semester at Uni learning python. I've really enjoyed it, and was hoping for a few tips on how to write more 'pythonic' code.

This is the `__init__` class from a recent assignment I did. At the time I wrote it, I was trying to work out how I could re-write this using lambdas, or in a neater, more efficient way, but ran out of time.

```
def __init__(self, dir):

    def _read_files(_, dir, files):

        for file in files:

            if file == "classes.txt":
                class_list = readtable(dir+"/"+file)
                for item in class_list:
                    Enrol.class_info_dict[item[0]] = item[1:]
                    if item[1] in Enrol.classes_dict:
                        Enrol.classes_dict[item[1]].append(item[0])
                    else:
                        Enrol.classes_dict[item[1]] = [item[0]]

            elif file == "subjects.txt":
                subject_list = readtable(dir+"/"+file)
                for item in subject_list:
                    Enrol.subjects_dict[item[0]] = item[1]

            elif file == "venues.txt":
                venue_list = readtable(dir+"/"+file)
                for item in venue_list:
                    Enrol.venues_dict[item[0]] = item[1:]

            elif file.endswith('.roll'):
                roll_list = readlines(dir+"/"+file)
                file = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
                Enrol.class_roll_dict[file] = roll_list
                for item in roll_list:
                    if item in Enrol.enrolled_dict:
                        Enrol.enrolled_dict[item].append(file)
                    else:
                        Enrol.enrolled_dict[item] = [file]


    try:
        os.path.walk(dir, _read_files, None)
    except:
        print "There was a problem reading the directory"
```

As you can see, it's a little bulky. If anyone has the time or inclination, I'd really appreciate a few tips on some python best-practices.

Thanks.

Comment: Note: this was part of a module called `enrol`, containing the `Enrol` class for which this is the `__init__`

Comment: looks like you got a classmate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943396/python-need-some-help

Comment: This looks *remarkably* like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943396/python-need-some-help

Comment: @Xavier @Johnsyweb, thanks for the heads up. The assignment was due on    sunday (30th), but have pulled the code until after marking and notified the lecturer.

Answer (score 5):

Couple things that can clean up your code a bit:

Use the dictionary's setdefault. If the key is missing, then it sets it to the default you provide it with, then returns it. Otherwise, it just ignores the 2nd parameter and returns what was in the dictionary. This avoids the clunky if-statements.

```
Enrol.venues_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(file)

>>> x = {}
>>> x.setdefault(99, []).append(5) 
>>> x.setdefault(99, []).append(6)
>>> x
{99: [5, 6]}
>>> x.setdefault(100, []).append(1)
>>> x
{99: [5, 6], 100: [1]}
```

The other possibility is to use os.path.join to make file paths. This is safer than just doing string concatenation.

```
os.path.join(dir, file)
```

Other than that, looks good in terms of style, IMO.

Comment: Thanks, that's a much neater way of implementing if/elif.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to orangeoctopus's suggestions to use `setdefault`, you can refactor the if-else into a dispatcher (the typical replacement for big if-else and switch statements):

```
# list of 2-tuples: (bool func(string filename), handler_function)
handlers = [
  ((lambda fn: fn == "classes.txt"), HandleClasses),
  ((lambda fn: fn == "subjects.txt"), HandleSubjects),
  ((lambda fn: fn.endswith(".roll")), HandleRoll)
]
```

then do

```
for filename in files:
  for matcher, handler in handlers:
    if matcher(filename):
      handler(filename)
      break
```

Comment: Wow, that great! I was looking for a large if-else and switch alternative, and found a few, but nothing this clean. Python just keeps getting better and better ;) Thanks Richard!

Comment: just to clarify, `HandleClasses`, `HandleSubjects` etc are functions with a `filename` parameter? And I'd still need them defined in the `_read_files` function in order to access the `dir` var?

Comment: Yes, correct.  You'd need them defined someplace where those symbols are defined.  You could do it in `__init__` as `self.HandlerSubjects`, too.

Answer (score 2):

Another important point if you want to use you script for long (some would say very long) is to not use deprecated functions in new code:

`os.path.walk` dissapeared in python 3.x. Now you can use `os.walk` instead. However `os.walk` is different to `os.path.walk` : it does not accept a processing function in its signature. So refactoring your code will imply a little bit more than changing names.

Comment: thanks joaquin. Someone else pointed that out to me in another post. Again, I didn't have time to change it before submitting it, but I;ll have a look at that now.